# document file doesn't want to open anymore. What to do?

Tags: libreoffice

I have worked with Ubuntu for a few months. Before there hasn't been a problem in opening Word Excel document file. But since the last 5 days the Ubuntu program opens fine and all the icons of the document files are visible but I'm unable to open them.
What need to be done to access those documents again.

Comment: what program are you opening the document with and what error message do you get ?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to open the document from inside Libreoffice, instead of from the Files Explorer.

Comment: Yes, open LibreOffice Calc then try to open the XLS or other spreadsheet file. Open LibreOffice Writer and try to open the DOC or other word processing file. This will tell us if the document files have been corrupted or have permissions problems vs your Desktop having lost track of which app should open a file. Also, would you please be so kind as to advise both the version number of LibreOffice (Under Help on its menu) as well as the type and version of Ubuntu (or Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu) you're running.